Merge conflicts dialog not showing on Git > Pull in PhpStorm
I used to use git pull all the time from the menu and I would be prompted with the merge conflicts dialog. In recent months, it just fails telling me 'I have divergent branches and need to specify how to reconcile them.' So, instead I am using Git > Merge from the menu, and manually dealing with conflicts when I have to.
I also looked in the git window under local changes because their documentation showed a link there to get the dialog, but there is none.  I just keep getting the 'divergent' error.
How do I get the dialog to show up for a Git > Pull? Or is this new behavior?
I'm working from the same GitHub repos I always have, and this seems to have become a new problem over the last few months.  Ideas?  Does this conflicts box come up automatically for you?

Perhaps you updated your version of Git? I suspect adding the global default setting for how to pull will resolve your issue. See this question for details.

@TTT I did try setting those different options, but none of them made the dialog pop up, and I still just get the message that they are divergent branches.  :(
